# How to get Spin.js spinner to delay before stopping?

Tags: javascript, spin.js

I have code like this

```
 var opts = {
    lines: 11, // The number of lines to draw
    length: 28, // The length of each line
    width: 25, // The line thickness
    radius: 35, // The radius of the inner circle
    corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
    rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
    direction: 1, // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
    color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
    speed: 1.3, // Rounds per second
    trail: 61, // Afterglow percentage
    shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
    hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
    className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
    zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
    top: 'auto', // Top position relative to parent in px
    left: 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
};
```

And then I call the spinner like this:

```
var target = document.getElementById('foo');
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
//do other stuff here
spinner.stop();
```

But I want to delay the spinner for sometime before it stops. How to achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean delay? You want it to spin for at least x number of seconds?

Comment: @Liath Yes, that's what I want it to do

Answer (score 2):

```
var target = document.getElementById('foo');
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
//do other stuff here
// use setTimeout to add a delay to the stop
setTimeout(function(){
 spinner.stop();
}, 1000);
```

This will call `spinner.stop()` after 1000 milliseconds. You can change it to whatever you want.

Comment: Great minds! Sorry I can't +1 you I've used my quota :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) method.

Your intialisation remains the same

```
var target = document.getElementById('foo');
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
```

Then you'd call

```
setTimeout(function(){spinner.stop()},5000);
```

After the given number of milliseconds the function will execute and stop your timer.